# How to catch C++ exception code in iOS Objective-C?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, exception

I'm new to iOS programming, now I met a problem related to catching the exception code threw from a C++ class.

```
    @try {
        myCPPClass myObj ; //this throws integer exception codes
    }
    @catch (...) { //I want to catch the integer value here, how ??
        NSLog(@"Exception:") ;
    }
    @finally {
    }
```

I knew it maybe not a good practice coding Objective-C in exception catching style, I'd like to know how to make custom exception class for C++ classes in Objective-C ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your objective-c `.m` source files to have the `.mm` extension. They will then be compiled as objective-c++ which is fully compatible with objective-c while offering all the facilities of c++.

then you can catch c++ exceptions with the usual

```
try {
   ...
}
catch(std::exception& e) {
   ...
}
```

construct.

Comment: objective-c is horrid. You'll want to use c++ for all your logic and just use obj-c to communicate with iOS when you have to interface with the gui.

Comment: Did this, still not catching any exceptions from C++.

Comment: @ErikAigner if you open a new question and provide an MCVE I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to Richard's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201462/how-to-catch-c-exception-code-in-ios-objective-c#:%7E:text=try%20%7B%0A%20%20%20...%0A%7D%0Acatch(std%3A%3Aexception%26%20e)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20...%0A%7D) for those still not catching any exceptions from C++.

Use this instead of `try catch`.

```objectivec
@try { } 
@catch (...) {
  NSLog(@"Exception:");
}
```

Why?

> Objective-C catch clause taking a dynamically
> typed exception object (@catch(id exception)) can catch any
> Objective-C exception, but cannot catch any C++ exceptions. **So, for
> interoperability, use @catch(...) to catch every exception and @throw;
> to rethrow caught exceptions.** In 32-bit, @catch(...) has the same
> effect as @catch(id exception).

- [C++ Interoperability](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Articles/Exceptions64Bit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009044-SW1)

Still, not catching any exceptions?

> - Don’t specify the `-no_compact_unwind` flag.
> - Specify the -funwind-tables flag if you’re including plain C code.

- [Addressing Language Exception Crashes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-language-exception-crashes)